# Method to upload and store images in db

Tags: php, mysql

I’m creating a db wich basically handles a music album artwork and their different sizes. An album artwork consists of a thumbnail, main cover image, zoom image and other type of images. Size ratio aspect is different depending on the format of the album. So a thumbnail for a CD album could be 50px by 50px, but for a CASSETTE, it could be 35px by 50px...

i.e:

- A CD will contain a front cover artwork (type) in 3 or more sizes (thumbn, main, zoom, etc..)
- A CD will also contain a inlay cd artwork (type) in 3 or more sizes (thumbn, main, zoom, etc..)

Searching the net, there seems to be different methods to achive this.

Method 1:

- Have a form with input fields to enter the data
- Have an upload input field to upload an image (good quality image... let’s call it imageX) that will be use to create the different sizes.
- Validate if imageX is acceptable (size, type, etc...)
- Create, on the spot, the different sizes and add a record in the db for each size created. The size (width and height) and the filename is included for each record

Database model:

```
artworktype 
========== 
artworktype_id, artworktype

artworksize 
========== 
artworksize_id, artworksize 

artwork 
========== 
artwork_id, album_id, artworktype_id, artworksize_id, filename, filenamewidth, filenameheight
```

Pros:

width and height are included (no need to launch PHP’s imagegetsize to get the size)

Cons:

Redundant data?

Method 2:

- Have a form with input fields to enter the data
- Have an upload input field to upload an image (good quality image... let’s call it imageX) that will be use to create the different sizes.
- Validate if imageX is acceptable (size, type, etc...)
- Create, on the spot, the different sizes and move them to the filesystem accordingly (naming convention to be determine)
- Create a record in the db for only the uploaded file.
- Let PHP determine the size and use the name convention to get to the other sizes

Database model:

```
artworktype 
========== 
artworktype_id, artworktype

artwork 
========== 
artwork_id, album_id, artworktype_id, filename
```

Pros:

No redundancy

Cons:

Need PHP’s getimagesize function to get the size. For an image, that’s acceptable. But, for many images (like a batch of thumbnails) that could be a strain to the server.

Is there a standard out there to achive this? How do others do it? Any opinions?

**EDITED**:
i'm not a fan of binary data in the db... so that option is out the question...

Comment: See This link ;D  http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/

Comment: I would use method one to get the best user experience and lower server load. If I had to use method 2, I would probably not use `getimagesize` and send the images without sizes to the browser.

Comment: Use method 2, and name the pics like `{w}x{h}_{id}.jpg` [or .png or whatever, so you don't need to call any function.

Comment: moonwave99: Im not sure if having the size in the filename is a good idea or a disaster waiting to happen...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `blob` for this. I have done in a similar application. Check out my code:

#### PHP Code:

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$data = addslashes($data);
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
fclose($fp);
if(mysql_query("UPDATE `entries` SET `phblob` = '$data', `phtype` = '$type' WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'"))
    $uploaded = true;
```

#### The database dump would be:

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phblob | longblob      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phtype | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

#### HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" type="file">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, i'm not a fan of binary data in the db... So basically, method 2 is your choice (without the binary data)

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, why so? Any issues?